# Wallpaper/background switcher for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, desktop, desktop-customization

I'm looking for a background switcher that has these features:

- Add folders to use as source of wallpapers (usually called 'monitor folder')
- Enable/disable those folders (not just add/remove)
- Crop and resize (usually called just "Zoom" in Ubuntu)
- Play, pause, stop, next, previous, redraw, and open wallpaper options on the launcher shortcut, or in the mini icon in the top bar (don't know how to call those icons)

So far the best I found is "Wallch", but it lacks some of the features mentioned above. In Windows I used "John's background switcher".

Is there anything like this for Linux? I'm using Ubuntu 12.

Comment: I can't say for sure that this has ALL the features you require, but i recall it being very extensive. Have you tried it?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wally/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just pust [Wallch](http://wall-changer.sourceforge.net/) as the winner.

It does not have all the features just yet, but I contacted the developer and he added what was missing, and will be available on the next release.

Comment: Wallch [is discontionued](https://alternativeto.net/software/wallch/?license=opensource), a good alternative may be [Variety](https://peterlevi.com/variety/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Desktop Nova](https://launchpad.net/desktopnova) or [Sync Wall](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/syncwall-wallpaper-changer-with-multi.html)(Has nearly all the features you asked for) and there a list of wallpaper changers in [Lifehacker AU](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2008/08/more_solutions_for_autoswitching_linux_wallpaper-2/) and [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/400505/rotate-desktop-backgrounds-in-ubuntu).